# How to apply an accordion to a Listview item?

Tags: android, android-listview, accordion

Hey guys I have used Listview I want when user clicks on Listview it open another layout or you can say like accordion style.

I searched on this but not getting exactly how to do that?

```
 public class CustomList extends SimpleAdapter {
        private View.OnClickListener callback;

        private Context mContext;
        public LayoutInflater inflater=null;
        public CustomList(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to , View.OnClickListener callback) {
            super(context, data, resource, from, to);
            mContext = context;
            this.callback = callback;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi=convertView;
            if(convertView==null)
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, null);
                vi.setOnClickListener(callback);
                vi.setTag(position);
                TextView lay = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.arrow);
                lay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        LinearLayout li = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.popup);
                        li.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });



            HashMap < String, Object > data = (HashMap<String, Object>) getItem(position);
            TextView text = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.carprice);
            String name = (String) data.get(TAG_CITY);
            Log.i("City", name);
            text.setText(name);
           // TextView text1 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.arrow);
            //String name1 = (String)data.get(TAG_CITY);
            //text1.setText(name1);
            TextView text2 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.carname);
            String name2 = (String)data.get(TAG_CITY);
            text2.setText(name2);

            ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.carimg);
            String image_url = (String) data.get(TAG_ID);
            Log.i("City", image_url);
            Picasso.with(this.mContext).load(image_url).into(image);
            return vi;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you're talking about [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)?

Comment: yes actually i have used listview to take dynamic data from url in json for the same each listview items need to open when user click is it possible in listview or not ?? or may be i have to switch to expandable Listview?? please suggest .!!!

Comment: Yes, it's possible with ListView (e.g: you add an extra view inside your item,initially with visibility GONE, then you play with visibility GONE/VISIBLE on item click). But in my opinion, its better if you use  ExpandableListView for that purpose.

Comment: @Rami ..I tried with that but my app is crashed when i click on listview item have you done before ..??

Comment: Post your code and the logcat

Comment: @Rami please check I have updated the code ..!!! still when i click i want to open a Linear layout on Listview like simple accordion .!!

Comment: @siddharth Log cat.. we need some error message to know where and why its going wrong :P

Comment: **1):** This code won't compile because there is no return outside the if block. ---- **2):** Inside the if block you should just inflate the layout, all the rest of stuff (click listeners, setting texts...) should be outside. ---- **3):** in *view.findViewById(R.id.popup)*, *view* represent *lay* TextView so *view.findViewById(R.id.popup)* should be *vi.findViewById(R.id.popup)* otherwise you'll have null value in *li*, so calling *li.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);* in a null value will cause the NullPointerException.